# Creating CloudKit records on scheduled days

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm working on an app right now that lets the user create new records on a recurring basis, and lets the schedule how many days in advance they want to create those records. This will almost always take place at a time when the app is not running, so I'm exploring my options for getting the app to be woken up to create the objects. As far as I see it there are four options, one of which is probably not really an option, since I'm trying to use only CloudKit and avoid creating a server-side component.

Option 1:
Use Background fetch to periodically refresh the records and check to see if anything is changed. In this instance I would probably have some kind of CloudKit record that represented the recurrence, in addition to the record type that needs to be created. Then I can just check the recurrence object and create a new record if needed

Option 2:
Schedule a local notification when the user schedules the recurrence. I thought this was going to work, but as far as I can tell, the app will not actually be launched even if it's a silent notification, unlike remote notifications.

Option 3:
Write some code locally that will check a data structure whenever the app is launched to check to see if any new records need to be created.

Option 4:
Create a server application that will create the records for me. Like I said, not really something that I want to do, even if it's the "best" option usually.

Answer (score 0):

With option 1 you can not be certain that your app is running.
Option 2 won't work. As you said the app won't be activated. Or the notification must nog be silent and the user has to select to open the app.
Option 3 is much better than 1 and 2 if you don't mind that it could happen that the records won't be created for a long time if the user never opens up your app.
Option 4 is the best option for this. you will have full control over when to add what.

But... Do you already know in front what data to add? Then why are you adding that data? Can't you just calculate it and assume it's there? Maybe even based on a settings record or so?

Comment: I would think that option 1 is more reliable than option 3. Yes there's no guarantee that you'll be called for background fetch every interval, but probably more likely that the system is going to wake you rather than the user.  I left a part of this out also, in addition to creating the CloudKit record, I need to create something via the Trello API, which is why I don't want to create everything up front.